# Error when looping on keyboard input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object, input

I have a loop that is supposed to store information into an array of objects, but for some reason, it always skips the first input.

```
public class GerbilData {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many different food items do the gerbils eat?");

    int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Food[] gerbilFood = new Food[n1];
    String temp;
    int temp2;
    int count = 1;

    for (int a = 0; a < n1; a++){
        gerbilFood[a] = new Food();
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (j < n1){
        System.out.println("Name of food item " + count + ":");
        temp = keyboard.nextLine();
        gerbilFood[j].setName(temp);
        count++;
        j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`keyboard.nextInt()` is only reading an integer from the keyboard, not reading the return character. So, when you first call `keyboard.nextLine()` you get the `\n` of the `getInt()`.

Try this instead :

```
int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```